# Swift 3 - how to use table position in another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swift3, uiviewcontroller, cgrect

Very new to Swift, kind of learning as I go.

ThirdViewController is a mapView with a slightly transparent TableView on top - on the Right hand side of the view.

I have a separate info view and xib - that will appear when one of the annotations is tapped, however Im trying to position it with CGRect -

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { [weak self] in
        let frame = self?.view.frame
        let yComponent = self?.partialView

        let tVC = ThirdViewController()

        self?.view.frame = CGRect(x: ((tVC.view.center.x) - ((frame?.width)!/2) - (tVC.mapTable.frame.minX)), y: yComponent!, width: frame!.width, height: frame!.height) 
})
```

ThirdViewController.swift controls the map and TableView (called mapTable).

When I run this it crashes - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It runs fine when tVC.mapTable.frame.minX is not used, but that brings it up in the middle of the View and overlaps the TableView a bit.

How can I use the tableView position to modify where my info view will appear.

I have set TableView up as an IBOutlet with ThirdViewController with dataSource and delegate outlets.

Do i set the IBOutlet in ThirdViewController's ViewDidLoad? - what I tried didn't work.

The map and table are both loaded before the info view is called so im not sure how to reference the tableview.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This: `let tVC = ThirdViewController()` is creating a new object that is not the one on the screen and which does not have a `mapTable` initialized.  How does your existing `ThirdViewController` get created?  Whatever creates it should make a reference available to the code you posted.

Comment: its created in story board and linked to ThirdViewController.swift. map and tables are IBOutlets 
eg. @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

at the beginning of the class 'ThirdViewController'

Comment: It's designed in the storyboard but it's created as an object when something instantiates it either in code or through a segue.  However that happens is the key to getting the reference you need.